# Page-break-inside support in phantomjs on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, phantomjs, buildpack, page-break-inside

I have a NodeJS app using PhantomJS to generate PDF files. My app is deployed to Heroku and I'm using [this](https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs) phantom build pack. Unfortunately this build pack does not support the `page-break-inside: avoid` CSS property.

I did a research and found 2 hacks on [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10638) GitHub issue page. I've tried both of them, but unfortunately I can't use the CSS one, due to my page structure and the JavaScript one isn't page-breaking properly.

One of the guys in the GitHub link above mentioned that this problem is fixed if I compile from source, but I have no idea how I can compile from source on Heroku App and is it even possible. All the buildpacks I found are using the binaries.

It's really important for my app to break pages properly, but I can't find a way to get this feature working. Any suggestion/guide about how to fix my issue will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've downloaded it to my machine(Debian 7.6.0) and compiled PhantomJS using [this](http://phantomjs.org/build.html) guide.
So I executed:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential chrpath git-core libssl-dev libfontconfig1-dev libxft-dev
git clone git://github.com/ariya/phantomjs.git
cd phantomjs
git checkout 1.9
./build.sh
```

And then I took the binary from `/bin` folder and added it to custom buildpack. I added this buildpack to heroku, but it crashed with the following error:

```
/phantomjs: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./phantomjs)
```

So I did on my machine

```
ldd bin/phantomjs
```

and I took all dependencies:

```
    root@deepsypotato:/home/viktor# ldd phantomjs.1
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe9f74000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fd914fcd000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fd914d96000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd914b91000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd914989000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd91476d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd914465000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd9141e3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd913fcd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd913c41000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd915283000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd913a2a000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fd913800000)
```

then I copied `libstdc++.so.6` from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` and added it to my custom buildpack and now its working flawlessly :).