# Heroku Library Dependencies via Buildpack, Phantomjs + Webfonts (but generalizable to buildpacks)

Tags: linux, heroku, dependencies, phantomjs, buildpack

After forking this Heroku buildpack (for phantomjs, but I imagine this issue applies for other custom buildpacks) :

https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs

and updating the compile script to pull from a custom phantomjs tar.bz2 file whose bin/phantomjs binary is replaced with this one:

http://arunoda.me/blog/phantomjs-webfonts-build.html

The Heroku build process works correctly, extracts the correct modified binary, but upon getting it to rasterize a web page, comes up with error message (via heroku logs, sans timestamps for succinctness):

```
app[web.1]: phantomjs: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by phantomjs)
app[web.1]: phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by phantomjs)
app[web.1]: phantomjs: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by phantomjs)
```

I've tried simply including these files within the tar.bz2 file in various configurations (in different /lib or /usr/lib locations) but this hasn't worked.  I realize there's a possibility of having to add some additional path information to the compile script in the buildpack, but perhaps because I'm not quite an Ops person I don't quite get it.  Add in the research on buildpacks and people referring to the base /app directory and the compile script having a vendor one, I'm even more confused.

I think this is possible to solve: in fact, it appears that [Deepsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2183827/deepsy) has solved the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756135/page-break-inside-support-in-phantomjs-on-heroku) by stating "then I copied libstdc++.so.6 from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 and added it to my custom buildpack and now its working flawlessly :)"

The problem for me, like the bulk of this post is pointing to, is that I don't know what that one line entails, and would greatly appreciate any help.  I've spent way too many hours on this, and am genuinely stuck.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**

I found Deepsy's code in his github repo [here](https://github.com/deepsyx/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs/blob/master/bin/compile) and tried to do the same curl approach, also updating the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and chmod 777ing the folder's contents (which includes both the binaries and library files).  This didn't work (the same error messages come up).  Also, my binary requires libc.so.6, which his didn't, but I got that file from my OS.

Interesting too: when trying to add and mv the libc.so.6 library file into the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, my Heroku app crashes.  I suspect this might be that adding that library to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH might confuse other binaries within Heroku and use my version, which for whatever reason isn't working for the Heroku instance.

**Update 2:**

I also tried building the phantomjs binary from scratch and was successful.  Turns out I get the exact same sized binary from the second link from the top, and the same calls for the necesarry libraries (thus same errors).

**Current thesis:**

It might be that the phantomjs binary is seeing the correct lib files given Update 1, but the provided Heroku ones aren't up to date enough for the binary to run correctly.  Or it could still be missing the library files.

Either way, I guess I'd need to somehow get phantomjs to use the library files I've provided, and I'm not sure how I'd get to do that.